# My Baker’s Public Key has changed - baking on my node

Tags: node, ledger, baker

My ledger had a different public key tz1 address when I was baking with BakeChain. Do I transfer my rolls to the new public key tz1 address now that I am baking with my node?

Comment: Which signing curve did you import on your new node? The ledger supports 3 different signing curves `ed25519` `secp256k1` and `P-256`. Perhaps BakeChain was using a different one than you are using now?

Comment: More information can be found here: https://github.com/obsidiansystems/ledger-app-tezos#importing-the-key-from-the-ledger-nano-s

Comment: ed25519....which gave me a PKH ...I have also added the previous tz1 address....  ssd to know command to use bake with original account and not PKH

Comment: Problem solved...registered with root by mistake

Comment: Nice! Maybe just answer your own question with what fixed it so your question get's marked as answered?  There should be a button below here that says "Answer your own question" or something similar.

Comment: @Adi_daz please answer your own question and mark it resolved! otherwise we believe it is pending. Please help your moderators!

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled ledger app and registered the ledger with the proper PKH....not the root!